# Insert image to img tag in Run-Time Text HTML Generation using c #

Tags: c#, html

I am generating a report in PDF, I use an HTML template that I convert to PDF, I have problems when inserting an image that should go in the report, this image is passed as a parameter in the partial class of my .tt file of the form: System.Drawing.Image MyImgParam but failed to embed it in the HTML  tag

I tried to convert it to base64 as I read in the documentation but it does not show me the image

`` `C# 
    <img src="<# =MakeImageSrcData(ImgParamBase64;) #>" />
` ``

I would like the image I pass as a parameter to be embedded in the src property of my tag

Comment: Specify the mime type after `data:` e.g., for a `JPG` image, set `src="data:image/jpeg;base64,[TheBase64string]"`

Answer (score 0):

Change the way to pass the image, stop passing the Image object as a parameter and pass a string with the image converted to Base64 and then embed the code in this way:

```
<# string b64 = Base64String;
#>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,[<#= b64 #>]"/>
```